# How to link QtMain in CMake with Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, cmake, qt5

I upgraded my project code from Qt4 to Qt5. It uses CMake.
The conversion got well except for one line of Cmake commands related to Qt.
I can’t find in current documentation, like

- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/cmake-manual.html
- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qtmain.html

**How to link with QtMain from CMake (with Qt5)?**

It is the only missing bit to convert my project.
Can someone point me to a doc explaining this or explain how to do it with Qt5? My Qt4 code worked correctly but I can't find the Cmake macro for Qt5.

EDIT> Here is the CMake file I have at the moment: https://bitbucket.org/klaim/aos_qt5/src/593c195c4c6889f6968d68fca018ef425783a063/tools/aosdesigner/CMakeLists.txt?at=wip_qt5

All qt5 necessary CMake macros have been set correctly I belive, the only thing that don't work is the linking to QtMain that do nothing, as expected since there should be a Qt5 specific way of doing it that I don't find in the Qt5 documentation.

You can browse the file history to see how it was working with Qt4.

Comment: How does your current link code look like?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Here it is: https://bitbucket.org/klaim/aos_qt5/src/593c195c4c6889f6968d68fca018ef425783a063/tools/aosdesigner/CMakeLists.txt?at=wip_qt5

Comment: What is the actual error message or problem you are encountering?

Comment: @DavidGrayson There is no linking happening with QtMain which makes the compilation assume that the standard main() function is the one to call on startup, which is not the right one on Windows as it is not a console application but a GUI one. The purpose of QtMain is to provide a WinMain() implementation that will call your standard main() implementation on Windows without displaying a console or having the project having to be a console project. It's purpose, more generally, is to allow the user to write a standard c++ main function used on all platform and hide the Windows specifics.

Comment: @DavidGrayson The problem is that (if you look in the history of the document linked), with Qt4 there was a way to link to QtMain (that is still in the current CMake file), but all CMake macros changed in Qt5 (to make it simpler to use Qt with CMake, so it's only good changes) but nowhere in the doc they explain what is different or how to link with QtMain, even it there is documentation about Qt5 version of QtMain. So I let the Qt4 way of doing it, but as said before, it's not linking with QtMain.

Comment: Can you show us the CMake artifacts from your project, please?

Comment: @dschulz Sorry, what are CMake "artifacts"?

Comment: `CMakeLists.txt` and other CMake related files..

Comment: @dschulz It's in the second comment. I'll move it in the question.

Comment: And does ${QT_QTMAIN_LIBRARY} actually points correctly to qtmain.lib?

Comment: @Archie No, I've told several time it's not linking, the variable is empty because not defined because Qt5 has changed.

Comment: Well, in this case, while waiting cmake scripts to be updated, why don't you link it yourself? You have a Qt path variable, just append qtmain.lib (or qtmaind.lib for debug build) and link it with your target.

Comment: @Archie My first reflex was to link directly with "qtmain.lib" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/cmake-manual.html) you linked to, it seems you can find Qt5Core instead of Qt5Widgets.  That will create an imported target named `Qt5::WinMain`.  From the [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/cmake-manual.html#imported-targets):

> Imported targets are created for each Qt module. That means that the `Qt5<Module>_LIBRARIES` contains a name of an imported target, rather than a path to a library.
>   ...
>   Each module in Qt 5 has a library target with the naming convention `Qt5::<Module>`

```
find_package( Qt5Widgets REQUIRED )
find_package( Qt5Core REQUIRED )
...
add_executable( aosdesigner WIN32 ${AOSDESIGNER_ALL_FILES} )
target_link_libraries( aosdesigner
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    utilcpp
    aoslcpp
    Qt5::WinMain  # <-- New target available via find_package ( Qt5Core )
)

qt5_use_modules( aosdesigner Widgets )
```

I'd also recommend that you remove your two `link_libraries` calls since it's a [deprecated command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3alink_libraries) and I'd specify CMake version 2.8.9 rather than just 2.8 as the minimum required at the top of your CMakeLists.txt, since [that's required for `qt5_use_modules`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/cmake-manual.html#using-qt-5-with-cmake-older-than-2-8-9).

Comment: The first suggestion can't work as there is no directory with a WinMain module. The second works, but then it trigger an error because it's a static library and it's compiled with vs2010 and I'm using vs2012. So the second part being more complete than the other answer, I'' accept this answer. Please remove the first part.

Answer (score 7):

As of CMake 2.8.11 and Qt 5.1, linking to Qt5::WinMain is automatic/implicit if you specify WIN32 in your add_executable call, or otherwise set the WIN32_EXECUTABLE target property.

The presentation at

https://devdays.kdab.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/cmake.pdf

with video at

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=GJ0kMsLbk6Q#t=751

describes the features which made it into CMake 2.8.11.

For more about CMake with Qt see

http://www.kdab.com/modern-cmake-with-qt-and-boost/

Comment: Note that the automatic adding of Qt5::WinMain target is subject to the `POLICY CMP0020` cmake policy. Default is the old behavior (not to add it).

Comment: Your comment is misleading. The default behavior is NEW if the minimum required cmake version is 2.8.11.

Comment: From http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/policy/CMP0020.html: "This policy was introduced in CMake version 2.8.11. CMake version 2.8.12.20140121-g1eb4d warns when the policy is not set and uses OLD behavior. Use the cmake_policy command to set it to OLD or NEW explicitly." So, as I read it, at least for the newest version, default is OLD, no matter what minimum required cmake version is - or is the default behavior changing depending on the required cmake version? If so, any documentation sources for it, or is it undocumented?

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-policies.7.html  The cmake_minimum_required() command does more than report an error if a too-old version of CMake is used to build a project. It also sets all policies introduced in that CMake version or earlier to NEW behavior.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT : Thanks to Archi comment (see below), simply add

```
target_link_libraries(<your_app> Qt5::WinMain)
```

or

```
target_link_libraries(<your_app> ${Qt5Core_QTMAIN_LIBRARIES})
```

in your application's CMakeLists.txt. Both syntaxes worked for me.

Comment: According to this presentation: https://qtconference.kdab.com/sites/default/files/slides/cmake.pdf ${QT_QTMAIN_LIBS} is not required, but just add_executable(exec WIN32 ...)

Comment: @Tawene I don't understand what is Qt5::WinMain? A new target?

Comment: Yes, Qt5::WinMain is a new target created by Qt5Core cmake files. Does this line helped you ?

Comment: The first line works. As the other answer was more complete I'll accept it but thank you and I voted for this.

Comment: How about on Linux? Qt5::WinMain sounds very Windows specific. Must we crack open a beefy `if (MSVC)`...