# Windows C++ GUI application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmake, qt5

I am currently working on porting my C++ Qt5/CMake application from linux to windows. When start application in linux, i see UI and all ok. On windows first start black terminal and from terminal start my application. How start application without black console? It is not beautiful.

I am using MSVC cmake generator and visual studio 2013 express.

Thank you all!

Comment: Add the `WIN32` parameter to your `add_executable` right after the application name.

Comment: The black terminal means you have built the program with console subsystem. Just build the program with GUI subsystem instead. If you have a standard `main`, then since you're using Microsoft tools you will have to tell the linker to use your standard main, using option `/entry:mainCRTStartup` (if I recall the entry function name correctly). This can possibly be done in some very simple way via CMake. Check it out, but don't heed any advice to start #if-ing and WinMain-ing and other such stupid stuff. Well unless you especially like that.

Comment: Ok. i try replace `wWinMain` to `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit CMakeLists.txt for create **WIN32** application

```
IF(MSVC)
    SET(OPTIONS WIN32)
ENDIF(MSVC)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(${APP_NAME} ${OPTIONS}
    ${HEADER_FILES}
    ${SOURCE_FILES}
    }
```

Edit main.cpp for using **wWinMain** and convert input args to **argc**, **argv**

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#   include <windows.h>
#   include <shellapi.h>
#endif

/// ... some code

#ifdef _MSC_VER
INT WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR, INT)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hInst);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);

    int argc;
    char** argv;
    {
        LPWSTR* lpArgv = CommandLineToArgvW( GetCommandLineW(), &argc );
        argv = (char**) malloc( argc*sizeof(char*) );
        int size, i = 0;
        for( ; i < argc; ++i )
        {
            size = wcslen( lpArgv[i] ) + 1;
            argv[i] = (char*) malloc( size );
            wcstombs( argv[i], lpArgv[i], size );
        }
        LocalFree( lpArgv );
    }

#else
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#endif

    QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);

    /// ... some code

    int code = a.exec();

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    {
        int i = 0;
        for( ; i < argc; ++i ) {
            free( argv[i] );
        }
        free( argv );
    }
#endif

    return code;
}
```

Comment: If you link with qtmain you do not need to mess with main.cpp.

Comment: Here is that for Qt5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115024/how-to-link-qtmain-in-cmake-with-qt5

Comment: A standard C++  `main` function always suffices. To avoid the console window the OP should simply specify the GUI subsystem. How to do with Qt and CMAKE and stuff, so that it works with different compilers & systems, is just a matter of looking at it, possibly reading docs.